# Where's this walkable cliff in Francois NL?

Tags: identify-this, newfoundland

Note the human standing at the edge. How do I walk to it? From [Newfoundland Labrador Tourism's Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bm3zxwpj9PW)

[image]

Comment: It may not be a cliff.  You only need a slightly concave landscape to create the illusion of a cliff from a vantage point several metre away.  In Norway, there are easily many thousands of places where one could take such a photo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky because the elevation maps Google Earth uses do not seem to be very high resolution for this area of the world. However, the following might be the location.

I can't seem to find much information about walking tracks in the area, so I'm not certain about this. It's about 5 km over rough terrain from the village of Francois. Or, it could be a quick helicopter trip for a photo!

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's overlooking Aviron Bay from the end of Bagg Pond. 
 For those who don't have Google Earth installed, here's the web link: https://earth.google.com/web/@47.5639944,-56.80518171,-0.26797501a,1314.71363018d,35y,-11.60108278h,75.97134349t,0r